# Surjective nonexpanding map between metric spaces with the same diameter is an isometry?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, lipschitz-functions, isometry, metric-geometry

Let $(X_1,d_1),(X_2,d_2)$ be **compact** connected metric spaces, and let $f:X_1 \to X_2$ be **surjective and non-expansive** ,i.e $$d_2(f(x),f(y)) \leq d_1(x,y).$$

Assume $\operatorname{diam}(X_1)=\operatorname{diam}(X_2)$. Is it true that $f$ is an isometry?

(The answer is known to be positive in the case where $(X_1,d_1)=(X_2,d_2)$).

**Update:**

It turns out the answer is negative ($f$  does not have to be an isometry, see Daniel Fischer's answer below).

*An interesting point:*

There is no way to adapt Daniel's idea to create a "smooth" (Riemannian) **one-dimensional** example.

Since every two compact connected one-dimensional Riemannian manifolds with equal diameters are isometric, there exists an isometry $\phi:X_2 \to X_1$.
Thus, $f \circ \phi:X_2 \to X_2$ is a surjective nonexpanding map from a compact metric space to **itself**, hence an isometry.

It turns out that it is possible to build Riemannian examples in higher dimensions where $f$ is **not** an isometry (see again Daniel's answer).

Comment: I've added an example for manifolds with boundary. I don't immediately see whether we can do it for compact (Riemannian) manifolds without boundary.

Comment: Try maps between ellipsoids $X_1, X_2$ of revolution with the same largest axis but the orthogonal cross section of $X_2$ is strictly smaller than the one of $X_1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$f$ need not be an isometry. Let $X_1 = [0,3],\, X_2 = [0,2]$, and $d_i(x,y) = \min \{ \lvert x-y\rvert, 1\}$. Then $X_1,X_2$ are compact metric spaces with diameter $1$, and $f \colon x \mapsto \frac{2}{3} x$ is a non-expansive homeomorphism that is not an isometry.

Regarding the addendum: If we allow manifolds with boundary, we can take for example two ellipses with the same diameter, like

$$X_1 = \bigl\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \tfrac{x^2}{100} + y^2 \leqslant 1\bigr\},\quad X_2 = \bigl\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \tfrac{x^2}{100} + 4y^2 \leqslant 1\bigr\}$$

with the Euclidean metric inherited from $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $f \colon (x,y) \mapsto (x,y/2)$ is a non-expansive diffeomorphism but not isometric.

I think we get an example without boundaries for ellipsoids

$$X_1 = \bigl\{ (x,y,z) : a^2 x^2 + b^2 y^2 + c^2 z^2 = 1\bigr\},\quad X_2 = \bigl\{ (x,y,z) : a^2 x^2 + b^2 y^2 + d^2 z^2 = 1\bigr\}$$

and $f \colon (x,y,z) \mapsto (x,y,cz/d)$ with $a < c < d < b$ when $a$ is small enough, $b$ large enough and $d-c$ small, but without computation, I can't guarantee that the diameters are indeed equal [that the points farthest apart in both ellipsoids are $(-1/a,0,0)$ and $(1/a,0,0)$].

Comment: Thanks! Very impressive. Your beautiful construction had also the positive side-effect of forcing me to prove to myself that the metric diameter of the ellipse is indeed the largest of the two "diameters" (a fact which I wasn't aware of). Thanks again.